# Traveling to Scotland 7/25-8/5

Tags: scotland, edinburgh

Traveling to Edinburgh then up to the Highlands then to Ie of Skye and finally to Glasgow. Any tips on what to pack for clothing?

Comment: Edinburgh these days is hot during days but cold outside at night. I was there a few days ago

Comment: Whatever clothing you pack, don’t forget insect repellant - the midges are fearsome this year!